# Strange behavior of an HTML list with a specific CSS

Tags: html, css

With this CSS:

```
li { margin-top: -1px;   }
li:before { content: "x"; float:left; }
```

under `<!doctype html>`, a standard `<ul>` list shows a shifted pattern:

[image]

Why?

Removing `margin-top: -1px;` or making it positive cancels the effect: the list is shown normally.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u285d6dL/2/). I checked in FireFox, Chrome, IE.

The list was

```
<ul>
    <li>y</li>
    <li>y</li>
    <li>y</li>
</ul>
```

Note: my question is *not* how to avoid it, but *why* it happens -- to understand how CSS works.

Comment: `li:before {position:absolute}`

Comment: To people answering, please note the OP is asking "Why" and not "How to fix this?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The floated elements are clipping / stacking.

Use `background: red;` on  `li:before` to see it.

[Here is the updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9bp0pkyr/)

Either remove the `float: left;` or the `margin-top: -1px` to fix it.
I'd suggest both - the `float` does nothing and instead of the `margin-top`, you can use `line-height`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better for you to actually show what you said? And thus actually give a more complete answer ?

Comment: The red color helps indeed to understand what's happening! As to removing things, this is irrevelant: this MWE is taken from a large project where floating was really necessary.

Comment: The interesting thing is they all seem to occupy the same space. https://jsfiddle.net/9bp0pkyr/1/ check the borders. They start and end at the same point.

Comment: You are displaying the border of the `li` items, not the `li:before` that are causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason for floating the pseudo element? If you remove or clear the float, it works

```css
li { margin-top: -1px;  }
li:before { content: "x";  }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>y</li>
    <li>y</li>
    <li>y</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you! But the question was about why it happens, not how to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `float: left` or else it considers it as aligning to the left of **the end of the previous object**

Answer (score 0):

That's happening because you are using `float:left`, you just need to remove this property and it will work perfectly fine. Below is the updated code:

```css
li {
  margin-top: -1px;
}

li:before {
  content: "x";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>y</li>
  <li>y</li>
  <li>y</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty interesting. I think there are a couple of interesting regressions happening because you do `margin-top: -1px` and you also float a pseudo element inside the `<li>` which causes some interesting things with the document flow.

Removing one or the other makes it seem to work as expected.

You could also put a `clear: both` on the `:before` pseudo element which will specify to the browser that the floating elements shouldn't try to float on the same line. That also seems to help a little.

I actually think the heart of the issue lies with the fact that `<li>` by default comes with its own "margin-top" with the default style of `-webkit-margin-before: 1em`. It seems setting `li` to have a style of `-webkit-margin-before: 0em` also solves the issue. For more information of `-webkit-margin-before`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33574237/what-is-the-difference-of-margin-top-and-webkit-margin-before)

In all honesty, I'm still looking into it so I'll try to update my answer if I can. One thing I am looking into is it could be the result of [margin-collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) but I don't have enough evidence to support it.

Specifically this excerpt might suggest a clue:

> When negative margins are involved, the size of the collapsed margin is the sum of the largest positive margin and the smallest (most negative) negative margin.
>
> **If both are negative, the greater negative value is used. This definition applies to adjacent elements and nested elements.**
>
> **Margins of floating and absolutely positioned elements never collapse.**